# How page expire or session expire works on refresh or back button?

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee

Can anyone please explain how can we make a page expire when click on back button? 
If we put response header as noCache does this work?
I have seen many online banking sites where session gets expired when trying to refresh a page or when trying to perform another action before getting the response for previous action or use back button. How this can be achieved in easiest way?

Thanks

Comment: `... many online banking sites where session gets expired when trying to refresh a page or when trying to perform another action before getting the response for previous action or use back button.` - This is actually not recommended from a POV of usability. Any well-written written site can handle multiple form submits or the back button; the answer to handling these web-UX problems is not to expire the user's session.

Answer (score 0):

If each action on the page is POST with hidden random-generated field, you can catch the situation where same POST is done twice (with GET you can try the same trick). You can then match the situation, where

1. User refreshes page
2. User click 'back' button
3. User works in 2 browser tabs/windows

Generally speaking, you can match any out-of-order user interaction, and session expiration can be one of the possible actions. From my observations, some bank system use such system, to prevent out-of-order user interactions.